# Code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

Tags: ios, xcode6, code-signing

I'm trying to build an app on device (iOS 7.1.2) using Xcode 6, however, it's always failed with error:

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 8.0'

The project's deployment target is 6.0.

Anyone be in stuck with this type of error?

Any suggests are appreciated!

Comment: if you have test target in project settins.select the target and delete it and try to build

Comment: @NarasimhaiahKolli Just search test target on Build Settings but see nothing. Could you please tell me how to find that test target? Thank you!

Comment: you will have two settings right 1 for general info another for setting below that target settings you will find test settings.delete that test settings.

Comment: @NarasimhaiahKolli Just found how to delete test target. Thank you for your support, it works!

Answer (score 4):

You need to set code signing for ***testing target*** separately even though you probably did set code signing on the main target.
This is what I did:
1. Select your test target
2. Set "Code Signing"->"Code Signing Identity" to your developer identity
3. Build 
Hope this solves it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works for me which is mentioned by Z S in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109851/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-unit-test-bundle-in-sdk-ios-8-0):

Going to Edit Scheme, then in the Build section, removing my unit test target from being invoked in "Run".

Comment: In Xcode 6.1.1, the "-" button is grayed out if I select the testing target.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this issue.And also I resolved it

Please follow the below steps:

1.Go to Project setting.In left panel see there is Targets.

2.Clicked on (your Project name)Tests.

3.Go to Info. There assign the proper Bundle identifier.

4.Go to build setting->Code Signing

5.Here set the Code Signing Identity and Provision Profile.

6.Clean the Build.

Now build your project .Its fine now

Answer (score 0):

The tests should run on a simulator. The first thing to do is to check that your target device is one of the simulators and not a hardware device.

Comment: This looks more like a comment, please move it to the comments.

Answer (score -2):

I understand hugoX has solved the problem but failed to explain it how he solved it.

These instructions are for xcode 6.1:

- Goto your project settings
- In the left pane, select your test target
- Press the delete key.

Even though this makes the project build successfully, you cannot use unit tests. If somebody has other solutions, that would be great.

Comment: These instructions will delete your unit testing target, which means you will unit tests will no longer run for your project. That's a very poor solution to the problem.

Comment: In Xcode 6.1.1, the test target does not appear to be deletable. The Delete option on the context menu is grayed out.