# create static library on iOS 8.1 with real device

Tags: static-libraries, code-signing, ios8.1

since I am quite new in iOS programming and still learning something new every day. So I tried something new.

I want to create a static library with the help of this link ([How can I create static library and can add just .a file on any project in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589359/how-can-i-create-static-library-and-can-add-just-a-file-on-any-project-in-ios))

I also could import my classes and insert them, but they use some specific code, which is not supported by the simulator, only by a real device like an IPad.

But when I hit the build button I get the error under the tests:

```
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'
```

As far as I could find out, it has something to do with the code signing identity for the tests . I don't use any of these tests by now and I already checked some of the articles here in that forum, but I couldn't figure out how to fix that error.

Has anybody some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109851/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-unit-test-bundle-in-sdk-ios-8-0). May be the code signing identity is automatic, so set it to a specific profile.