# Getting error on building a app on Xcode 6.1?

Tags: ios, xcode6, code-signing, codesign, code-signing-certificate

I "m building an app on Xcode 6.1  and iam facing a problem when i click on build in Xcode
getting an error like below:

```
  CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'
```

I google and get some similar links related to this issue but all are for **SDK 5.1 or 6.0.**

Could anyone help me how i can solve this issue.
Help is appreciated!

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109851/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-unit-test-bundle-in-sdk-ios-8-0

Answer (score 3):

[image: CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 8.1']

Remove any blue check in [ProductName]Tests so it will be uncheck then try running.

Comment: How can I get this screen in XCode?

Comment: You can view it on the "Edit Scheme".. it is near the "Play & Stop icon". It is the name where you click and changed your device or simulator to run your build.

Comment: This seemed to be the only solution that works for my project. Tried several suggested solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure,i think **provisioning profile** in the build settings for the test target was set to **"Don't code sign"**. select provisioning profile manually. May be it will solve your issue.
for change provisioning profile identity

select your project title and the right side view

```
Go to Build settings->Code signing-> Code signing identity->(if its in Don't code sign )then select your provisioning profile.
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem and i am not able to figure out how to proceed with it. could you please tell me exact steps to solve it.

Comment: i have implemented this but still i am not able to build the app on device. probably there is some error in provisioning profile. Could you please help me with te exact action steps

Comment: My suggestion is try to  create new project and add old files.. :),after try to build the app.

Comment: refer this link to create provisioning profile http://www.download-youtube-video.net/icreateapp/create-provisioning-profile.html

Comment: Hi, I have Applied all the steps but still i am not able to build the app. could you please tell me any better way.