# CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Static Library' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.4'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I couldn't figure this one out

In xCode I have a run script build phase which runs "xcodebuild" to test the project on simulator.
When I run the following line in the script:

```
xcodebuild -workspace Augury.xcworkspace -scheme "Augury - Production" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s" test
```

It fails with the following message:

```
=== BUILD TARGET Pods-FMDB OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
Check dependencies
CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Static Library' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.4'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged.
=== BUILD TARGET Pods-Raven OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Static Library' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.4'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged.
=== BUILD TARGET Pods-CPAnimationSequence OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Static Library' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.4'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged.
=== BUILD TARGET Pods-MBProgressHUD OF PROJECT Pods WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Static Library' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.4'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged.
Testing failed:
CodeSign error: entitlements are required for product type 'Static Library' in SDK 'Simulator - iOS 8.4'. Your Xcode installation may be damaged.

** TEST FAILED **
The following build commands failed:

Check dependencies
Check dependencies
Check dependencies
Check dependencies
(4 failures)
```

I've tried various suggestions and non worked:

- I tried running "xcodebuild install" & "xcodebuild build" and it fails with the same messsage
- Following some of the suggestion in other questions asked here I tried reinstalling xCode but that didn't help either

FYI: When I run the same code in the terminal directly in runs just fine,
also when I run the `xcodebuild test` with actual device in the destination it runs just fine

I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the same like this one.

[Code signing is required for product type Unit Test Bundle in SDK iOS 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109851/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-unit-test-bundle-in-sdk-ios-8-0)

Hope the answer marked as the right one can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, 
It seems that my pods project isn't code signed, and I don't know if I should code sign it, but the thing is I manage to build it in xCode and also run it with xcodetool in terminal, the only way it throws this error is when running in a "Run Script" build phase