# iOS code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 9.2'

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

I want to test my application in iPhone 5s. and it have latest ios version. so, I have deleted old Xcode V 7.0.1 and install a new version v 7.2.

After installing v 7.2 I am getting below error.

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Unit Test
>   Bundle' in SDK 'iOS 9.2'

I have check this question [code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-unit-test-bundle-in-sdk-ios-8-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109851/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-unit-test-bundle-in-sdk-ios-8-0) and try all the answers but still I am getting this problem.

I have proper set build target in general as well as info tab. even I am not getting code signin error to fix the issue. but still not able to run application in my testing device.

[image]

Code signing also set correctly.

[image]

Also deleted Test Project from my Application.

Answer (score 6):

I found solution for that work for me. in the left panel, go under projectNameTests then in signing choose any development team that has license in ios.

Answer (score 2):

Actually for every iOS app there will be **two targets 1.app target 2.test target**.
Code signing is required for both targets.In our case,code signing is not set for test target , so *click 'app_name'tests under TARGETS section* and provide same code siging details as given for app target

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Change the target on left top to appName**Tests** and set signing section accordingly. Now signing error should go.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go to Edit Scheme, then in the Build section, removing any unit test target from being invoked in "Run" and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the build device. I had selected my iPhone, when in fact it should have been any simulator. As soon as I changed it to a simulator, the tests ran fine.