# Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

i don`t know why this error.
 i did everthing about it. 
does anyone give me a keyword about it

**Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'** i have this error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code signing is required for product type Unit Test Bundle in SDK iOS 8.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109851/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-unit-test-bundle-in-sdk-ios-8-0)

Comment: it doesn`t work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0' - StickerPackExtension requires a development team error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37806538/code-signing-is-required-for-product-type-application-in-sdk-ios-10-0-stic)

Answer (score 2):

You must register device to run the app , click none and select your developer account

[image]

Try to change the bundle - id , un check automatic and re check it again

Comment: i got this error "Signing for "Sporting" requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor."

Comment: i want to test my app by free. i didn`t pay apple account

Comment: you must at least create a free account to run on the device

Comment: yes i create a account and in signing i register my personal team but it doesn`t work

Comment: Unchecking and checking back "Automatically manage signing" did work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you have registered an account for free, you would only be able to use it for **1 week**, and the maximum devices you can link to is **3**.

When did you create your account? If it was over a week ago, you would have to make a new account to develop an app for free, sadly. :(

[Reference](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/47843)